# Running a VBA Loop with Selenium to scrape html data into Excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, selenium

I was recently assisted in scraping data from a webpage by the guys at Stackoverflow. It's a great community.  I was given a function that pulls data into excel from a cell containing a url.  Unfortunately I'm running into some problems because I need a loop function so that Excel does not restart all my functions once I save or refresh the page.

So far I have tried to build this, but am next to useless in VBA. Wondering if anyone can provide a little extra assistance.

```
Sub POSTPageViews()
Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim AllWords As Range
Dim text As String
Dim OutValue As String
Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
On Error Resume Next

Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
driver.Start "chrome", "https://re.po.st/"
driver.Open strLocation

Set InputSheet = Active
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
WordListSheet.Range("E1") = "All Words"
InputSheet.Activate
r = 1

Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
  Cells(r, 1).Value = txt
OutValue =        driver.findElementById("sguidtotaltable").findElementByTagName("span").text
 Next i
r = r + 1
driver.stop 'Stops the browser
Loop
End Sub
```

But naturally it is not working... Anybody see what is wrong? Basically in Column E I have all the URLs and in column K I would like to see the accompanying values.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but I see a `Next i` with out a `For i` or any other reference to `i` for that matter.

Comment: Also, getting rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, at least for the moment, will allow the editor to tell you where your code is going wrong and why.

Comment: mmhm, I've taken that out but still problematic. I'm thinking that I have to define StrLocation? to be Column E?

Comment: Says "Object Required" after I removed that...

Comment: If `strLocation` is where your url is, then I would put it inside your loop. Maybe something like this: `driver.Open Cells(r, 5).Value`. and you can place `driver.stop` outside of the loop. The results could be in column F, maybe, like `Cells(r, 6) = driver.findElementsById(...`

Comment: Did you remove both `Next i` and `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Yes I did. Will continue editing Cells (r,5)

Comment: The problem is the lack of Object.  I'm not sure what is going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work (in the spirit of my comments)?

```
Sub POSTPageViews()
Dim driver As SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver

Set driver = New SeleniumWrapper.WebDriver
driver.Start "chrome", "https://re.po.st/"

With Worksheets("Trial")

r = 2

Do While .Cells(r, 5) <> ""
driver.Open .Cells(r, 5).Value
.Cells(r, 11) =    driver.findElementById("sguidtotaltable").findElementByTagName("span").text
r = r + 1

Loop
driver.stop 'Stops the browser
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the name of the sheet with the urls? I think we can clean up where you are activating and selecting various sheets and ranges.

Comment: Just says Object Required, can't figure out what is going wrong there.

Comment: Name of sheet is "Trial" url column is E and output column would be K :)

Comment: OK. I edited this code in a way that I think will help and get to the heart of the matter. Try it, please, and tell me what happens.

Comment: Just give me a minute, Struggling with wifi (of course :/ ) maybe just a bit longer than a minute

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Matt. This works like a charm.